# How to rename only certain columns names in a data.frame by adding a prefix?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this

```r
df = data.frame(
  do_not_rename = 1:3,
  rename1 = 1:3,
  rename2 = 1:3)
```

and suppose I want only rename those that starts with `"rename"` to `"finished_renamex"` by adding a "finished" in front.

How do I do that? Imagine if I have thousands of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R, we can use `startsWith` to identify column names which start with a prefix

```
inds <- startsWith(names(df), "rename")
#Or grep
#inds <- grep("^rename", names(df))
names(df)[inds] <- paste0("finished_", names(df)[inds])

df
#  do_not_rename finished_rename1 finished_rename2
#1             1                1                1
#2             2                2                2
#3             3                3                3
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `dplyr::rename_at` and `start_with` helper

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with('rename')), ~paste0('finished_',.))

  do_not_rename finished_rename1 finished_rename2
1             1                1                1
2             2                2                2
3             3                3                3
```

Using base R

```
colnames(df)[grep('^rename',names(df))] <- paste0('finished_',grep('^rename',names(df), value = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

In one line, you can do it with a [`gsub`](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/rw1001/library/base/html/grep.html)

```
 names(df) <- gsub('^rename(.)','finished_rename\\1', names(df))

 names(df)
 [1] "do_not_rename"    "finished_rename1" "finished_rename2"
```

If you have more than 9 of columns which are numbered like this, you should use the `+` character after the `.`

```
 names(df) <- gsub('^rename(.+)','finished_rename\\1', names(df))
```

Generally, gsub is the way to go though.